# Best Practices for Calling Scipy From C

Tags: python, c, scipy

I've written some C-code to call scipy functions.  The body, including variable declarations and using EXIT FAIL to denote messages and cleanup steps, is:

```
PyObject *module_name, *module = NULL;
PyObject *funct = NULL;
PyObject *output = NULL;
int  j;
double dInVal, dOutVal;

Py_Initialize();

module_name = PyString_FromString("scipy.stats");
module = PyImport_Import(module_name);
Py_DECREF(module_name);
if (!module)
    EXIT FAIL

funct = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "beta");
if (!funct)
    EXIT FAIL
Py_DECREF(module);

for (j=0; j<=10; j++)
{
    dInVal = (double)j/10.0;

    output = PyObject_CallMethod(funct, "ppf", "(f,f,f)", dInVal, 50.0, 50.0);
    if (!output)
        EXIT FAIL

    dOutVal = PyFloat_AsDouble(output);
    Py_DECREF(output);
    printf("%6.3f %6.3f\n", dInVal, dOutVal);
}

Py_DECREF(funct);
Py_Finalize();
```

When I run this as the main routine, it appears to work fine.  However, when I run it as a subroutine, it works for a first call, but fails on any subsequent call.

The code does work as a subroutine after the first call, if I make all of the `PyObject` pointers static (and include the appropriate flags, so that Python is initialized and the "beta" object is imported only once), but make-everything-static seems like a brute force solution to the problem, especially if the program will eventually include more than one subroutine that calls Python.

My question is, what is the best practice for setting up a C-program, to call scipy from a subroutine?